# CSS not being applied when using domain name

Tags: html, css, iis-7.5

I am having a problem with certain css applying under IE 8 when I use the domain name. The css works fine when I use the ip address. If I test with Chrome or FF the css works fine using either the ip address or domain name.

The problem with this section of code is that the exclusions should have an arrow next to it and list T and TB under it when it is hovered over. The code works perfectly using the ip address but the arrow and drop down list T and TB do not appear when I use the domain name. I am also having issues with other styles being applied from other style sheets as well when the domain name is used.

The site is being hosted under IIS 7.5.

Anyone have any recommendation on where to start troubleshooting this?

**styles.css**

```
#cssmenu{ height:37px; display:block; padding:0; margin:0;  border:0px solid; position: relative; top:-1px; width: 100%; } 
#cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; display:block; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; padding:12px 20px; font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); } 
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; border-right:1px solid; top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f; /*padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px;*/ top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:8px 20px; font:10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 
#cssmenu, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{ background:#4fbdf0; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #4fbdf0 0%, #45b2d2 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4fbdf0), color-stop(100%,#45b2d2)); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4fbdf0 0%,#45b2d2 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top,  #4fbdf0 0%,#45b2d2 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #4fbdf0 0%,#45b2d2 100%); /*background:linear-gradient(top,  #4fbdf0 0%,#45b2d2 100%);*/ filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4fbdf0', endColorstr='#45b2d2',GradientType=0); } 
#cssmenu{border-color:#3589a1;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{border-right:1px solid #3589a1; color:#fff;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{border-color:#6ed1ff;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover{background:#36acd2;}
```

**Index**

```
<link href="~/Content/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <div id="cssmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Imports", "Index", "Import")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Report")</li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Exclusions</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("T", "Index", "TExclusions")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("TB", "Index", "TBExclusions")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        @*<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>*@
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with IIS, but I would start by removing the tilde (`~`) from the `href`.  `href="/Content/menu_assets/styles.css"` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that and still the same issue.

Comment: Stuart Hallows answer [here][1] worked great.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100502/bootstrap-kendoui-localhost-works-fine-but-not-domain-name

Comment: if that works, see whether IE wants to render the site in compatibility view by default. If the IP address works differently than the domain name, IE must have decided to use compatibility view for the one but not for the other at some time.